# PostgreSQL muitos processos

Tags: banco-de-dados, postgresql

Tenho o PostgreSQL instalado em uma maquina onde roda um sistema, sendo que ao longo do dia vai surgindo diversos processos com `postgres.exe` e consome recursos da máquina. Em momentos chega a ter mais de 100 instâncias destes processos.

Alguma sugestão?

Versão: Postgres 9.2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No 9.2 desconheço alguma forma. No 9.4 em diante pode limitar o número máximo de processos ativos com a diretiva de configuração `max_worker_processes` ([documentação](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/runtime-config-resource.html)). Isso obviamente pode limitar a capacidade de responder às requisições, se está criando tantos é porque está precisando. Mas também tem casos que pode melhorar o funcionamento. Só testando em cargas reais para ver.

[Documentação completa das configurações possíveis](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/runtime-config.html).